# Nuxt - Splitting CSS into a separate file

Tags: css, vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js, seo

I'm working on project where we are building rather big e-commerce website and we have A LOT of CSS. We are using Nuxt 2, with Composition API and Server Side Rendering.

Default settings in our project makes it so that all the CSS is inlined into the rendered HTML. This makes initial HTML too big (more than 120 kB after compression). So I've tried using extractCSS settings to remove CSS from the HTML:
https://nuxtjs.org/docs/configuration-glossary/configuration-build/#extractcss

I moved all the CSS into a separate file using Nuxt config like this:

```js
build: {
  extractCSS: {
    ignoreOrder: true,
  },
  optimization: {
    splitChunks: {
      cacheGroups: {
        styles: {
          name: 'styles',
          test: /\.(css|vue)$/,
          chunks: 'all',
          enforce: true,
        },
      },
    },
  },
// ...
```

It causes page size to be cut in half (HTML weighs around 60 kB) so it is great outcome. But... Core web vitals are terrible. Mainly FCP and LCP are getting much worse, because we are waiting longer for the final styles to be applied. LCP is going from already bad 4 seconds to absolutely terrible 10 seconds (in mobile Lighthouse test with throttling).

I'm really out of ideas what I could do. I tried using extractCSS and not moving everything to a single file, but rather to a multiple file (not using the `optimization` in the config). But then metrics are even worse. Other tools like Critters seems to do the same thing (or I'm using them wrong).

How I can ensure that metrics are good, while keeping HTML size down? Only thing I can think of would be to remove styles that are not immediately needed from the `<style>` tag, put them into a separate files, and somehow load them asynchronously. In that way we should receive critical CSS inlined into the HTML (as we did previously before using extractCSS), and the rest would be loaded asynchronously a bit later. That is a theory but it would most likely take a lot of time, and is it even a good approach? How should I do this?